# Get Rid from Native Base fontFamily "Roboto_medium" is not a system... Error

Tags: react-native, expo, native-base

I'm using components from Native Base in my expo App but the error of font is irritating again n again. Kindly provide me the solution according to my code to get rid from this.
Thanks in Advance

Error

> You started loading the font "Roboto_medium", but used it before it
>   finished loading.
>
> - You need to wait for Font.loadAsync to complete before using the font.
> - We recommend loading all fonts before rendering the app, and rendering only Expo.AppLoading while waiting for loading to complete.
> - node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:59:8 in error
> - node_modules\expo\build\environment\muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
> - ... 24 more stack frames from framework internals

App.js

```
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoginScreen from './src/screens/LoginScreen';

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },

});

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

LoginScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import { Text, Container, Header, Content, Input, Item, Button, Toast, Root } from 'native-base';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            showToast: false
        }
    }
    async componentWillMount() {
        await Font.loadAsync({
          'Roboto': require('../../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
          'Roboto_medium': require('../../node_modules/native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
          ...Ionicons.font,
        })
      }
    onSubmit(ref) {
        Toast.show({
            text: "Username & Password are mandatory.",
            type: 'warning',
            textStyle: { fontSize: 14, alignSelf: 'center' },
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Root>
                <ImageBackground
                    source={require('../images/login-bg.jpg')}
                    style={styles.container}
                >
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" enabled>
                        <View style={styles.loginContaner}>
                            <Image source={require('../images/MMC-logo.png')} style={styles.logo} />
                            <Item regular style={styles.loginInputItem}>
                                <Input
                                    placeholder='Email'
                                    placeholderTextColor="#555"
                                    style={styles.loginInput}
                                    autoCapitalize="none"
                                    autoCorrect={false}
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ email: val })}
                                />
                            </Item>
                            <Item regular style={styles.inputPassword}>
                                <Input
                                    autoCapitalize="none"
                                    placeholder='Password'
                                    secureTextEntry
                                    placeholderTextColor="#555"
                                    style={styles.loginInput}
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                    onChangeText={(val) => this.setState({ password: val })}
                                />
                            </Item>
                            <Button block style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.onSubmit(this)}>
                                <Text>LOGIN</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </View>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </ImageBackground>
            </Root>
        );
    }
}
```

Package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "expo-font": "~7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and what I do is that import Text from react-native rather than native-base, and this solved my problem.

Give a try removing from import {Text} from 'native-base' and put this into 'react-native'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running app with expo and solved by following comment in native Base site :
NativeBase uses some custom fonts that can be loaded using Font.loadAsync. Please Check out the following address :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-base